# "error: package org.apache.commons.math3.random does not exist"?

Tags: java, apache, package

I'm trying to compile a java code as in the following line :

```
  javac -classpath /Users/tim/kws/code/library:/Users/moab/kws/code/commons-cli-1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/Users/tim/kws/code/commons-math-2.2/commons-math-2.2.jar:/Users/tim/kws/code/common-math3-3.1.1/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar RATSWriteLandmarksFromPfile.java
```

/Users/tim/kws/code/library/ppm/types/LabelPfile.java:17: error: package org.apache.commons.math3.random does not exist
import org.apache.commons.math3.random.RandomDataImpl;
                                      ^
/Users/tim/kws/code/library/ppm/types/LabelPfile.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
    private RandomDataImpl randomData_;
            ^
  symbol:   class RandomDataImpl
  location: class LabelPfile
/Users/tim/kws/code/library/ppm/types/LabelPfile.java:321: error: cannot find symbol
        randomData_ = new RandomDataImpl();
                          ^
  symbol:   class RandomDataImpl
  location: class LabelPfile
3 errors

does anybody know why am I getting these errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing the commons-math3 library.

Comment: you are right. i added that library too but it didn't change anything . i updated the original question accordingly with the same errors

Comment: Do you have a typo in your command? Shouldn't it be ````/commons-math3-3.1.1/```` in the path to the library? Also, do you need both commons-math-2.2 and commons-math-3.1.1?

Comment: wow..thanks a lot Lukas! i wouldn't have realized that stupid typo by myself!